# Select from union giving uncaught error exception

Tags: sql, union, wildcard

This is giving an uncaught error exception

I simply wish to select from two tables that have no relation, but who happen to have the same column names.
Do you know what is causing the error or is there a better of querying this?

```
        SELECT product_id, name , meta_keyword , category_id FROM 
        oc_product_description WHERE name LIKE '%$word%'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT name as 'category_name' FROM 
        oc_category_description WHERE name LIKE '%$word%');
```

Comment: `UNION` requires both parts to have the same number of columns (which should have the same type - or can be cast to the same type, depends on RDMS). Also, you have extra parenthesis at the end .

Comment: sorry Ill remove the parenthesis as thats probably confusing (its nothing to do with why its not working, but thank you I didnt realise that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components of a `union` should have the same number of columns (with compatible types) -- at least in most databases.  Try this version:

```
SELECT product_id, name , meta_keyword , category_id
FROM oc_product_description
WHERE name LIKE '%$word%'
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, name, NULL, NULL
FROM oc_category_description
WHERE name LIKE '%$word%'");
```

This seems like an unusual thing to do.  If I had to guess, you don't really want a `union all` query.  But this will fix the syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the`UNION`statement the columns in both`SELECT`statements has to match. Your error however doesn't sound like a SQL error but rather an exception that comes from the language you use, maybe Java or C#? You probably have to surround the SQL statement with a try-catch block and handle an SQL Exception or something similar.